# Populate UITableView datasource using struct instead of array

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a model for a user profile

```swift
struct Profile {
  let bio: String?
  let company: String
  let createdDate: Date
  let department: String
  let email: String
  let firstName: String
  let coverImageURL: URL?
  let jobTitle: String
  let lastName: String
  let location: String?
  let name: String
  let profileImageURL: URL?
  let roles: [String]
  let isActive: Bool
  let updatedDate: Date?
  let userID: String
}
```

I need to render a `UITableView` and assign each of these items to a row.

As this model is a single item, I am unsure how to achieve this, I had considered using [Mirror](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mirror) to iterate over the struct and map each value but that feels a little gross and I'd like to retain some form of control as to what is rendered.

How can I convert this model to a data type I can iterate over for a table view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a dictionary of the properties as keys and values like this and use the dictionary to iterate through the values.

```
struct Profile: Codable {
    //...
    func getProfileDictionary() throws -> [String: Any] {
        let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(self)
        return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any] ?? [:]
    }
}
```

Iterating through the key, values in the dictionary.

```
do {
    let dictionary = try profile.getProfileDictionary()
    for (key, value) in dictionary {
        print("\(key): \(value)")
    }
} catch { print(error) }
```